# Calculus，Limit， definite integral with variable upper limit

Tags: calculus

$$\displaystyle\lim \limits_{x \to +\infty}\frac{\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}{t|{\sin t|dt}}}{x^{2}}$$,
**How can I solve it? I need your help, thank you!
I want to divide them into many small intervals and try to use L'Hopistal, but it failed. And Squeeze theorem also failed.

Comment: I think you mean *limit*, not *limitation*

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: $\frac1{x^2}\int_0^xt|\sin(t)|\,dt=\int_0^1t|\sin(xt)|\,dt$.

Comment: Could you give me some more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $x\ge\pi$, there is $n\in N$ such that
$$ n\pi\le x<(n+1)\pi $$
and hence
$$ \int_0^{n\pi}t|\sin t|dt\le \int_0^xt|\sin t|dt\le\int_0^{(n+1)\pi}t|\sin t|dt. $$
Since
$$ \int_{(k-1)\pi}^{k\pi}t|\sin t|dt=(2k-1)\pi $$
for any integer $k$, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^{n\pi}t|\sin t|dt&=&\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{(k-1)\pi}^{k\pi}(-1)^{k-1}t\sin tdt\\
&=&\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)\pi\\
&=&n^2\pi,\\
\int_{0}^{(n+1)\pi}t|\sin t|dt&=&(2n+1)^2\pi.
\end{eqnarray}
So one has
$$ \frac1{(n+1)^2\pi^2}\cdot n^2\pi\le\frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^xt|\sin t|dt\le\frac1{n^2\pi^2}\cdot(n+1)^2\pi.$$
This implies
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^xt|\sin t|dt=\frac{1}{\pi}. $$